# How to take input in a vector inside a vector without knowing it's size?

Tags: c++, vector, io

So I had a question that required me to take input of a list of variable lists of which I was only given the list size and not the lengths of the variable lists inside it.

INPUT:

```
3
1 5 7 2
3 6 2 6 2 4
6 2 3 5 3
```

The first line of INPUT is the size of the list of lists, followed by input of each list which are variable in size. How can I take this input inside a `vector<vector<int>>` in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the thing with the help of the `std::stringstream` as shown:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    vector<vector<int>> mainVector{};
    string tempInput = "";
    int number = 0;
    int lines = 0;

    cout << "Enter the number of lines: ";
    cin >> lines;

    for (int i = 0; i <= lines; i++) {
        // temporary vector
        vector<int> tempVector{};
        // getting the entire inputted line from the user
        getline(cin, tempInput);

        // parsing the string into the integer
        stringstream ss(tempInput);

        // pushing the integer
        while (ss >> number)
            tempVector.push_back(number);
        
        mainVector.push_back(tempVector);
    }

    // displaying them back to verify they're successfully stored
    for (int i = 0; i <= lines; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0, len = mainVector[i].size(); j < len; j++)
            cout << mainVector[i][j] << ' ';

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**A sample output:**

```
Enter the number of lines: 3 
1 5 7 2
3 6 2 6 2 4
6 2 3 5 3 

1 5 7 2     // printing the stored vector
3 6 2 6 2 4
6 2 3 5 3
```

Comment: @SomeshwarRoychowdhury don't see if it works. See how it works.

Comment: Yeah! But I don't understand why the above solution needed cin.ignore() and also in the above solution while printing the values, the first value is absent from the first vector! Could you please explain that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `std::getline()` to input each line, then use `istringstream` or `std::stoi` to parse the `strings` into `ints`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector <vector<int>> DATA;

int main(){
    int N;
    cin >> N;

    string input;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        getline(cin, input);
    
        istringstream my_stream(input);
        vector <int> curr;

        int num;
        while(my_stream >> num){
             curr.push_back(num);
        }
    
        DATA.push_back(curr);

        cin.ignore();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am running the code on my laptop but it seems to take only one line of input after taking N even though I have input N as 2

Comment: Add `cin.ignore()`

Comment: Seems like you've forgot to implement `vector` library.

Comment: while printing the values, the first value from the first vector is missing !?